# Maven 3.0.2 -U option does not update snapshot

Tags: maven

Does anyone know why Maven 3.0.2 -U option does not update snapshot? The maven-metadata-repo.xml file gets updated, however, the SNAPSHOT jar doesn't. I've tried to put `<updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>` in the settings.xml, doesn't work either.

Thanks,
Jane

Comment: Are snapshots deployed using maven3?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Artifactory for your repository?  If so, you may be running in to an issue I struggled with. It is caused by incorrect Artifactory configuration. In the Artifactory documentation, see the part about "Maven 3 Only Supports Unique Snapshots".

http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Local+Repositories

Comment: Oh, man - thank you! This one has been bugging me for a while.